# Didn't getting any requests from jQuery ajax to JAVA RESTful webservice

Tags: ajax, web-services, jakarta-ee, apache2, jboss7.x

Please help me to solve this serious issue...

My web application is developed using 'html, javascript and css' for front-end & back-end with RESTful webservice in JAVA.

Front-end is deployed in Apache2 server & back-end in JBOSS 7 server. Currently the communication between front-end & back-end is not possible via jQuery ajax. There is not showing any error messages too..!  But didn't getting any request calls to the JBOSS server from the Apache server. I used 'application/json' as contentType. Here adding the code which I used...

```
$.ajax({

url : URL,
type : 'POST',
headers : {
            "ACCEPT" : "application/json"
      },
contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
crossDomain : true,
data : request,
dataType : 'json',

success : function(response){

          //my code
   },                                   
  error : function(xhr, status, error) {
          //my code
   }
 });
```

Hope you peoples will help me.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: happy to see here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
         data: { 
             'param1':'value1',
             'param2':value2,
            },
        dataType:"json",
        beforeSend:function(){
        },
        success: function(solution){
        },
        error: function(errorType, textStatus, errorThrown){
        },
        complete: function(){
        }

    });
```

In POST method in data field you have to send post parameters

Comment: Hi Prasad, Thanks for your reply... The request in data filed of my code is an object contains all parameters to be send to the server.  This code works fine when the back- end deployed in Tomcat server. But don't work with JBOSS Server.